# Problems with struct prototyping (Invalid use of undefined type) c++

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I want my caba stucture to contain a pointer to a variable of aba structure. And I also want aba structure to do some operations depending of properties of set < caba >.

But when I use properties of aba pointer inside caba, I get an error

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<set>
using namespace std;
struct aba;
struct caba
{
    aba *m;
    int z;
    bool operator >(const caba &other)
    {
        if(m==NULL||other.m==NULL)
            return true;
        return (*m).x>(*(other.m)).x;
    }
};
set <caba> t;
struct aba
{
    int x,y;
    bool f()
    {
        return !t.empty();
    }
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

sayng:

> In member function `bool caba::operator>(const caba&)':
>
> Test.cpp|13|error: invalid use of undefined type `struct aba'
>
> Test.cpp|4|error: forward declaration of `struct aba'
>
> Test.cpp|13|error: invalid use of undefined type `struct aba'
>
> Test.cpp|4|error: forward declaration of `struct aba'

But why is aba undefined? There is a prototype of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have *declared* aba, but your code needs the *definition* too. What you can do is move the offending code out of the `caba` class definition and into a `.cpp` implementation file which includes both `aba.h` and `caba.h`.

```
// caba.h (include guards assumed)
struct aba;
struct caba
{
    aba *m;
    int z;
    bool operator >(const caba &other);
};

//caba.cpp
#include "caba.h"
#include "aba.h"
bool caba::operator >(const caba &other)
{
    if(m==NULL||other.m==NULL)
        return true;
    return (*m).x>(*(other.m)).x;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. And isn't there a way to have both classes in one file?

Comment: It's better to have it the way juanchopanza suggested or you can try this  http://ideone.com/Vw4Vcz

Comment: @user2136963 Yes, there is, but you still have to put the definition of `bool caba::operator>` *after* the `aba` class definition.

Comment: @user2136963 Or just move `operator>` function definition under definition of `aba` should work.